# Count URL's in console instead of progress bar

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I currently run a progress bar as part of a web-scraper but it appears to be both

(A) Inaccurate
(B) Slow for what the process is.

```
with click.progressbar(range(1000000)) as bar:
    for i in bar:
        pass
```

Is there an article/training that I would be able to read to better understand printing progress to console?

I effectively want the program to scan a url in the list and then print progress as it iterates through the list, something along the lines of

- Scanning URL 1 of 30
- Scanning URL 2 of 30
- Scanning URL 3 of 30

If possible, keep on same line but not essential.

Code Is Below -- If someone could assist with either training or reading, it would be appreciated.

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html
URL_LIST = [
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-1-goldsmith-st-elwood-vic-3184",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-10-albion-rd-glen-iris-vic-3146",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-109-sydney-rd-manly-nsw-2095",
"https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-1110-glen-huntly-rd-glen-huntly-vic-3163",]

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print 'scanning url....'

        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
            (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
            writer.writerow([title, price, sold])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print an indicator *other* than a progress bar to show how far along you are, the easiest would probably be to do regular prints.

Since the code in the question is for Python 2, I originally answered with Python 2 code, however this question could just as easily come up for Python 3 users, so I've added a section for them too.

## A version for Python 2

The following is based on and should complement the code in the question:

```
for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
    print 'Scanning url #' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST))
```

You can also optionally add the url you're scanning by using the `url` variable your `for` loop generates.

Also, if you want to have each print replace the last, you can add a comma `,` to the end of your print statement, and add the `\r` character to the beginning:

```
for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
    print '\rScanning url #' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),
```

The comma prevents `print` from adding a new line character (`\n`) to the end, and the `\r` ("carriage return") at the beginning erases what's on the line already before printing the rest of the line.

## Differences in `print` between Python 2 & Python 3

It's important to note that `print` functions quite differently in Python 2 and Python 3. The above 'Python 2' solution will not work in Python 3.

For one thing, `print` in Python 3 is a function, not a keyword, so it has to be called as a function (i.e. `print('Print me!')`), and secondly, adding the comma to the end will not prevent the output of the new line character. *Normally* including a comma at the end would have no **visible** effect, however the interpreter *is* evaluating it (as a tuple containing a single `None`) as can be seen when using the Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). Instead, one must supply a named argument (named `end`) to the `print` function to override it's default.

## A version for Python 3

Here's a Python 3 equivalent to the code I supplied at the top of this answer:

```
for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
    print('Scanning url #' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST)))
```

And if you want to have each print reuse the same line, as the second example above:

```
for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
    print('\rScanning url #' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST)), end='')
```

In case you didn't read everything above, please note that `end=''` is overriding the `print` function's default action of adding a `\n` (newline) character to the end of each line so that it adds an empty string instead, and the `\r` (carriage return) character at the beginning of the string causes Python to go back to the beginning of the line to print the rest of the string.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, just need to shorten it a bit and remove the URL out of printing, but this is enough for me to grow on my own.

Comment: Just removed the last section -  so now reads
'Scanning url #' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST))
Output is now
Scanning URL #1 of 7

Comment: Not looking for a easy answer, as I like to try and work it out for myself - However is there a methodology so that it prints on the same line instead of carriage returns?

Comment: Sorry - Just incase you come back, I already have the answer
print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) + ' of ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),
Thanks again

Comment: Thanks, I've added the info to the answer, and also added info for Python 3 users.

Answer (score 0):

[tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a powerful progress bar library. It let's you do stuff like this.

```
import tqdm
t = tqdm.tqdm(list('abcdefg'))
for i in t:
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    t.set_postfix(url=i)
```

The progress bar output is:

```
 86%|██████████████████████████▏    | 6/7 [00:06<00:01,  1.00s/it, url=f]
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'm really trying to avoid a progress bar - I have that already, more looking to count + print each iteration as it occurs for a quick visual check on progress. Thank you for offering the assistance none the less